# How to use JW Player to play video in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, jwplayer

I have a rails application which use `Paperclip` gem to upload the videos and `paperclip-av-transcoder` gem to convert the format and size of videos.

Currently, I use

`video_tag vod.video(:sd), controls: true, type: "video/mp4", size: "400x400"`

to display the videos, but It can only display one format.

Therefore, I want to use JW Player to display the videos. But I didn't find the user guide in the official website. Even I cannot find the download link.

So how to use the jwplayer in my app? What html code and javascript code I should write in my html file?

Note: `@vod` is the model of video, `@vod.video` is the attribute to store the video

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/choix/jwplayer-rails

Answer (score 0):

Reference:

[Gem jwplayer-rails](https://github.com/choix/jwplayer-rails)

[Customization Reference](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference):

Add this line to your application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'jwplayer-rails'
```

First include assets on the page

```
<%= jwplayer_assets %>
```

Than place a div with JW Player

```
<%= jwplayer %>
```

You can pass options to jwplayer helper to customize it:

```
<%= jwplayer({file: vod.video(:sd), width: 500, height: 200}) %>
```

User JwPlayer without gem:

html:

```
<div id='myElement'>Loading the player ...</div>
```

jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var playerInstance = jwplayer('myElement');
  playerInstance.setup({ 
    file: '/uploads/example.mp4', 
    image: '/uploads/example.jpg'
  });
</script>
```

Link to setup start [guide](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413074).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but jwplayer-rails gem is out of date. and I want to use the newest version

Comment: From here you can link to download jwplayer. http://www.jwplayer.com/products/jwplayer/ and this is link to quick start guide https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413074

Comment: The link is asking you to sign up, and when you sign in you can enter a dashboard page, but no download link

Comment: https://dashboard.jwplayer.com/#/players/downloads?property=f7aeffd6-b397-11e5-848d-128293859c83